# Lodash pick values from ImmutableJS Maps into new object

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash, immutable.js

Is there a nice way to pick certain key/values out of an Immutable Map to return in to a new object/Map? Seems too linear with what I have currently:

```
const depart = flightStatusState.getIn(['activeTraveller', 'outbound', 'departMapData'])
const arrive = flightStatusState.getIn(['activeTraveller', 'outbound', 'arriveMapData'])

const departLat = depart.get('lat');
const departLng = depart.get('lng');
const arriveLat = arrive.get('lat');
const arriveLng = arrive.get('lng');

const outboundMapDataLatLngs = [{ lat: departLat, lng: departLng }, { lat: arriveLat, lng: arriveLng }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Lodash variation with [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) support in [Mudash](https://github.com/brianneisler/mudash) to use `M.pickBy` on an Immutable map and accomplished the following like so:

```
const outbound = flightStatusState.getIn(['activeTraveller', 'outbound'])
const outboundMapData = List.of(outbound.get('departMapData'), outbound.get('arriveMapData'))

const outboundMapDataLatLngs = outboundMapData.map(destination => 
  M.pickBy(destination, (value, key) => 
    _.startsWith(key, "l")
  ) 
)
```

(I needed `outboundMapData` separately aswell hence the 2nd line)

It then just uses the last line to pick out the nested lat/lngs into its own entity. `toJS()` from ImmutableJS is then used on `outboundMapDataLatLngs` in the component required to render it.